# In Intellij, right click on a test does not present a "Run" option

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ when I right click on a test I dont see a "Run ClassX or MethodY" anymore. In fact there is no "run" window and when I right click I cannot run any class.

It was all working fine about 3 hours ago so I am not quite sure what has changed.

IntelliJ 10.5.1 (Licensed and NOT community edition)
Java 1.6.0_24

This happens for all projects.

### Update 1

I installed IDEA 11 and imported settings from 10 and then saw that it was not a free upgrade close IDEA 11 and started using IDEA 10. I am fairly certain things stopped working from that point but not sure. Is that a problem? Can I somehow delete IntelliJ configuration directory somehow and restart?

Adding a screenshot when I don't get Run option on right click:

[image]

Comment: just checking, is the file recognised filetype (it normally has an icon next to it) under a source recognised folder?

Comment: Yes, I can see the J icon (not the J icon with a cross) in the class and the test

Comment: mm.. they are recognised as java files but don't show up as class or test files (other icons) that's probably why you are missing the Run options on your tests. Not sure why this is happening. I've seen it once when intellij was not indexing large java files

Comment: @CalmStorm, did you try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and restart? Make sure you are not using Oracle JDK, try to re-import the Maven project and rebuild.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Done invalidating caches reimporting the project files, deleted the ipr iws files too. This happens for all projects so must be something really bad.

Comment: Rename IDEA folders to start with the defaults: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181.

Comment: I mean delete/move away existing folders so that IDE starts with the clean settings (it will ask for the license, JDK, etc).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Just did that deleted {home}/.IntelliJIdea10 and 11. Started IDEA, asked me for the license file. Open a new project and NO joy there is no Run button yet and no way of opening a run window. This is just driving me nuts.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the right click menu? Did you try 10.5.4 from http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1228 or 11.1.3 from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok after tremendous amount of eyeballing I located a {HOME}/.java directory which seemed to contain some Jetbrains related preferences. I deleted that directory plus {HOME}/.IntelliJ* directories. Then deleted all my intellij installations and downloaded it again from scratch and it now works fine..

Sigh....

Comment: The .java dir didn't exist for me. and I'm pretty sure those are intellij settings directories, so don't wipe those unless you don't care that your settings will be lost.

Comment: @Amalgovinus, yes! Two notes: **1)** if you don't want to lose your settings, you probably can delete only `{HOME}/.IdeaIC15/system` folder and keep `config`. **2)** In my case of _SBT project_ it was enough to drop `.idea` project folder and re-import from SBT. Again, you may lose some project-specific settings in this case: determining the particular file that should be erased is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: had same problem. Closed project, deleted .idea directory and myProject.iml file. Created new project from existing sources. Reinstall is not necessary.

Comment: Had to delete old and new .IntelliJ directories. Had to set IntelliJ up from scratch, but it is only once a year.

Answer (score 62):

My problem was that my test class wasn't public. I needed:

```
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
```

instead of:

```
class MyTest {

    @Test
    void testMethod() {
```

Comment: this definitely works

Comment: correct! need to add public key word for class and method

Comment: same this happened to me on IntelliJ 2023.1.2, ironically i had generated the test-class via IntelliJ itself (right click on class > Generate > Unit test)

Answer (score 53):

If your project is a maven project then you can just right-click on the pom.xml file and select "add as Maven project".

This approach worked for me. (green plus third from the bottom)

[image]

Comment: i was banging my head like anything. and your solution fixed my issue in seconds. thank you.

Comment: Thanks.. This one helped me. I had the project added as Maven project. So I unlinked the project from maven( from the context menu on pom.xml file) and then added back as maven project and bingo.. Run options appeared

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem.  To fix it, I had to ensure that my class had a proper main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

Every keyword in the above statement is critical.  If you omit one, IntelliJ wont' recognize it.  Easy-to-forget keywords are static, void, and the String[] args argument.

I had forgotten the arguments in mine ;-)

Also make sure your source code is inside a `src` folder which is marked as such by IntelliJ.

Comment: I had missed the [] part

Comment: I have this but still there's no run button in IntelliJ IDEA when I click right. What's the problem with http://pastebin.com/XSYeHi2P ?

Comment: @Mona Jalal, I can't see anything by just looking at your code.  Here's my recommendation: Take everything out of the file after the main method and see if that works.  If it does, gradually add back in small parts until the "go" button goes away again. Then figure out what is wrong with that part.  Also, make sure to make args lower-case.  This won't break your code, but it is a convention that all Java programmers follow.

Comment: @JosiahYoder as odd as it may seem, I was only given the code and weirdly assumed it is a complete project. IntelliJ requires you to have your code inside the `src` folder hence I created a project which had a `src` folder and put my codes there and then I had run button upon right clicking on .java files with a main method

Comment: **"Make sure your source codes are inside a src folder"** saved me hours of time, thanks.

Answer (score 25):

In my case, the cause was disabled JUnit plugin. (File — Settings — Plugins — JUnit, check, OK)

Comment: The menu option does not exist in version 2019.2.3.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, I was scratching my head for hours and your answer solves my problem

Comment: For Mac, it is under File -> Preferences -> Plugins

Answer (score 18):

If you're using JUnit 5 (Jupiter), this happens when you use the old `@Test` annotation from JUnit 4. Just replace

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

with

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

and IntelliJ should show the "Run" button again.

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 10):

In my case i right clicked the src folder and went to -> mark directory as -> sources root.

Comment: For me this worked,+1, I hd polygot setup & forgot to mark scala as test sources root

Answer (score 7):

Disabling `gradle` plugin solved the issue for me (community edition 2018.2)

Comment: This worked for me with Ultimate Edition 2019.3.1.  Weird.

Comment: Same here. Seems like Gradle plugin was throwing some exception (look at Help -> Show Log in Finder).

Has this issue for 2019.3.1. Community Edition.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I solve it by
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
right click on the top pom.xml -> Maven -> reimport
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with a Kotlin project. Following action solved it:

- right click on `test` folder -> select `Mark Directory as` -> choose `Test Sources Root`

[image: mark as Test sources root]

Answer (score 3):

I could resolve the issue by disabling the **Gradle** plugin from the Plugin menu and restart.

Comment: This was my solution as well. To note: If you have the Gradle plugin enabled and you have the Gradle Extension plugin _disabled_ your run menu will not appear and IntelliJ will throw errors (which can be found in Help > Show Log in Finder). For me, enabling Gradle is fine, but without the Gradle Extension it breaks IntelliJ.

Comment: Worked for me in IntelliJ IDEA 2023

Answer (score 3):

If the project is already added as a Maven one, unlink it.

**right click on the project -> Maven -> Unlink Maven Projects**

Then link it again:

**right click on pom.xml -> + Add as Maven Project**

Answer (score 2):

There should be no need to delete any configuration files.

I found that I used to have the Run option in the context menu to select either run tests or run Scala tests, etc. After I had selected an option for the first time, my options were no longer there.

I was able to resolve this issue and select the type of tests I wanted for that folder by creating a Run/Debug configuration following the instructions found in the documentation here...

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html?origin=old_help

Comment: Just so you know, this is from an unsupported and *really* old version of IntelliJ, so I'm not sure how relevant this particular answer is towards this question.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Maybe someone having the same problem on 2016.1.1 or above might be helped by my answer.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem with the latest version of IntelliJ

Answer (score 2):

As i had the same issue , i could clearly See that @Test is not providing any hint when i press control key and hover , and the same was confirmed as External Libraries was not having Gradle Dependencies added so i had to update the project as gradle project suggested by a pop up when you start Intellij.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem and solved it in the following way.

Go to your $USER/$INTELLIJ directory e.g. $USER/.IdeaC2018.3 then find config/plugins.  Rename the plugins directory and restart IntelliJ.

My guess is that the problem was caused when I upgraded IntelliJ and incompatibilities with the cucumber plugin.

Answer (score 1):

For me this happened after updating Idea, and then updating all Plugins. Apparently Idea had not restarted yet. Going to `File -> Settings -> Plugins and clicking 'Restart Idea'` solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

if you can see the play button in left side of the main function then click right click and  press run.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I did not have an output folder.
file -> project structure -> under 'project' tab there's 'Project compiler output' -> define your folder.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of these worked for me. I had to

1. 'File' -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart"
2. Click on pom.xml file, and then 'maven' -> "Generate Sources"
   [image: maven, generate sources]

Answer (score 1):

Search for **pom.xml** file --> ***Right Click*** on pom.xml --> Click on **Add as Maven** Project.

You should get a pop-up, saying downloading Mavin Plugin.

[image]

Wait till it gets completed. It takes some time depending on the number of content in pom.xml.

In the below screenshot, "**BackendApp.java**" is Driver Java file that contains

> **public static void main(String[] args){}**

Right Click on such driver java file and you see Run option in green color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I had this problem on pycharm and the problem was that there was already a run configuration (in the dropdown next to the play button) that had the name of the file. When i deleted that run configuration it would create a new one that was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried all the above solutions nothing worked for me but after I install TestNG plugin it's started working since there are some TestNG annotations used in my unit tests

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Intellij 2019.3 after that I updated from 2019.2.4. I thought that the problem came from the updated first, but the rollback didn't fix, so I tried de solution above e the problem was fixed. After configuring all my projects from scratch the problem get back, so I started to check everything I did. I discovered that an old project from Eclipse that uses files ***.launch*** to run and need some plugins to be able to execute on Intellij was causing the problem, after disable the following plugins the test option return.

[image: plugins]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my project is using Bazel.

The solution was to **sync Bazel** from Bazel plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a top Google result when trying to figure out how to run a Scala project, and since for some reason IntelliJ (I'm on 2020.1.2) doesn't automatically create a run configuration for a Scala project (in contrary to a Java project), it's worth laying out the basics for future readers:

1. Click on "Edit Configuration" on the top right of the screen.
2. Inside the opened window, click the <kbd>+</kbd> button its top left.
3. Choose "Application".

Now, let's go through the required fields:

4. in the "Name" field, enter a name for this configuration, e.g. "run".
5. in the "Main Class" field, enter your main class name.
   Alternatively, use the <kbd>...</kbd> button to the left: inside the window that opens, click the "Project" tab, navigate to your main class, pick it and click "ok".
   Note: If your main class doesn't have a main method, IntelliJ would show an alert. see listing 9 below.
6. Make sure the value in "Working Directory" field is correct (it should be the project folder).
7. in "Use classpath of module", select your module (see [project vs module in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839461/libraries-projects-modules-and-packages-in-intellij-idea))
8. That's it for configuring. Click "Apply", and close the window. Here's an example final result:

[image]

- Note that my `Main` class is part of a package named `Demo`, but having a package is not necessary.

9. Inside the main class, make sure there's a main method.
   See [@Josiah Yoder answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19100245/3002584) for java, and for Scala it's:

   ```
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   }
   ```
10. That's it. You should now have the green run and debug buttons enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are version conflicts between plugins and IDEA itself that commonly break this functionality. Many of the solution here indicate people manually trying to identify the plug in, I found that to be impossible. So here is a generic way, without having to uninstall IDEA as one solution proposed:

File > Settings > Plugins > gear icon > disable all downloaded plugins

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the method is not `static`! JUnit only allows `@Test` before instance methods but Intellij doesn't complain even if you use `@Test` above a `static` method.