# Golang plugin on Intellij. Library and break points

Tags: go, intellij-idea, plugins, jetbrains-ide

I write my code on Go. I build my project in Idea Intellij with plugin for golang. I have a package main. In main import different packages.

```
import (
    "RF"
    "flag"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "depot"
    "info"
    "logger"
    "logic"
    "poly"
    "ranker"
    "revgeocoder"
    "search"
    "search/engine"
    "stat"
    "views"
    "fmt"
)
```

This packages very well linked if I write paths in `$GOPATH`. In Idea Intellij it makes such way:

[image: Path to packages]

Now, I want:

1. Build my project without warning
2. Debugging my project

---

First point. I make a 'build' and than I have: "Package is not specified"

[image: Package is not specified]

If I write to Package name `main`, than warning doesn't disappear:

[image: Cannot find package <code>main</code>]

What I can do?

---

Point number two. The assembly is successful. After that part of package I can debug, another package I cannot debug. For example package `engine` I can debug. Path to this package:

```
/home/INT.PV.KM/urvanov/hedgehogues/distr/mapsfullsearch/src/search/engine/engine.go
```

Next file I cannot debug.

```
/home/INT.PV.KM/urvanov/hedgehogues/distr/mapsfullsearch/src/search/context.go
```

[image: Tree of catalog]

I cannot set a breaks point in this file:

[image: Break point]

Please, help me with my problems.

Comment: I am trying next [LiteIDE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/liteide/files/X30.3/) and [here](https://github.com/visualfc/liteide)

Comment: Just to make sure you wont miss it: the team at Jetbrains is working on its own implementation of a Go IDE called Gogland. It looks very promising. As far as I know it's currently still in a closed Beta stage. Take a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/go/ for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The answer to the first question

Any project in Go consist of packages. There is nothing except for packages. All packages are located in the same directory, which one is project. Other directories are libraries. They set through environment variable `$GOPATH`. IDEA IntelliJ let make it as:

File->Settings:

[image: Outer packages]

There are two type of libs in Go: globals and locals. You read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844770/3696633).

In the build time is necessary to specify which package we want to gather and line up all the dependencies themselves. In my project, there are n packets. For example, I can build mapsfullsearch package. I can build mfsimporter package. Or I can build any other, in which there is `func main () {/*...*/}`. To build just specify the appropriate configuration.

After that, all Imports (if relevant packages exist), resolved.

[image: Struct of my project]

About configurations. Go to Run -> Edit Configurations...

[image: Settings of configurations]

Name: name of compilled file. 
Run kind: which type of building (file or package).
Package: package name that matches the name of the directory in which the `main()`. There are drop-down list in IDEA IntelliJ. It appears, if you start to write his name.
Output directory: directory where the binary.
Environments: variables of environments
Go Tool arguments: compiler's arguments
Program arguments: program's arguments

For more information about config can be read [here](https://rootpd.com/2016/02/04/setting-up-intellij-idea-for-your-first-golang-project/).

### The answer to the second question

In the IDEA may be poorly specified file path. In that case, to which I referred in her question, the problem was related to the fact that the path to the library is specified via the home directory, which is denoted by `~`. IDEA  does not perceive such format. Repeat this problem I did not succeed. Although up to the moment until I put the project in the root file system, my project didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

- Build my project without warning -> you need to use the full package name (for example you need to use "github.com/dlsniper/demo" for a package under the GOPATH `/home/florin/go` and full path `$GOPATH/src/github.com/dlsniper/demo`. Alternatively, you can use the `Run Kind` directory and point it to the directory or simply just use the green arrow near the `func main`, click on it, select `Run ...` and then select `Go Application`

---

- Debugging my project -> once you get your `Run Configuration` of type `Go Application` to run the application then to debug it you'll just need to use the Debug option instead of Run. Alternatively, you can click on the green arrow near the `func main` and choose `Debug...` to debug your application.

Comment: And the second one?